# Using syntastic with C++, how can you implement template classes without it giving errors?

Tags: c++, c++11, vim, syntastic

This compiles and seems to be OK. Resourceholder.hpp is included elsewhere.

However, in **resourceholder.inl** syntastic reports (on the second line) that "variable has incomplete type void".

Is there any way to make syntastic understand this kind of implementation? I mean specifically template classes that have seperated header from implementation.

**resourceholder.hpp**

```
#pragma once
#include<map>
#include<cassert>
#include<memory>
#include<SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "resources.h"
template <typename Resource, typename Identifier>
class ResourceHolder
{
    private:
        std::map<Identifier, std::unique_ptr<Resource>> mResourceMap;
    public:
        void load(Identifier id, const std::string& filename);   
};

#include "resourceholder.inl";
```

**resourceholder.inl**

```
    template <typename Resource, typename Identifier>
void ResourceHolder<Resource, Identifier>::load(Identifier id, const std::string& filename)
{
    std::unique_ptr<Resource> resource(new Resource());
    if (!resource->loadFromFile(filename))
        throw std::runtime_error("ResourceHolder::load - Failed to load " + filename);

    auto inserted = mResourceMap.insert(std::make_pair(id, std::move(resource)));
    assert(inserted.second);
}
```

Comment: What checker gives you the warning?

Comment: I ran SyntasticInfo and it tells me the current checker is gcc.

Comment: Syntastic doesn't know about C++ standards. It runs external programs, with the options you tell it to, and shows you the results in a window. You can __see__ the command lines constructed by syntastic in the debug logs (see `:h syntastic-config-debug`. You can __change__ the way syntastic constructs the command lines by setting the various checker options.  For recent syntastic versions you can see the available checker options in the manual (`:h syntastic-checkers`).  For syntastic 3.7.0 or earlier you can consult the [wiki](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/wiki/Syntax-Checkers).